# How can I format arguments in a string.format operation

Tags: c#, string, string.format

This isn't a serious problem, I was just curious.

I am formatting a string, the data in the output string reuses argument data several times, but changes the case (for example).

```
string data = "TEST";
string s = string.Format("{0} - {1}", data, data.ToLower());
// REQUIRED OUTPUT 
// TEST - test
```

But can I achieve this somehow...

```
// ****PSEUDO-code****
//string s = string.Format("{0} - {0}.ToLower()", data);
```

Comment: I believe something could be possible if you implement your own `IFormatProvider` and `ICustomFormatter`, but... it just doesn't worth the effort.

Answer (score 3):

There are many specifiers that allow you to format the data that replaces the formatting token ([this article is a good place to learn about those](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)).

Unfortunately there is no specifier that lets you do a `ToLower` on the string - you will have to do that yourself before you pass it to `String.Format`.

Comment: Thanks guys, it is what I thought, but I've been proven wrong so many times before, I thought I would check.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not possible.

When you pass in a `string` argument to `string.Format` it is left unchanged (barring alignment/width). There is no way to specify composite formatting that will manipulate a passed in `string` to change its case.